# Converting vanilla js to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my vanilla js

```
fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nabz123/9bef14fe98f95367887f827c3c5a0906/raw/01869dca62142c5ec0092316436cf3a7ecd7a8ec/topartists.json").then(
    res=>{
        res.json().then(
            data=>{
                var element ="";
                data.forEach((item) => {
                    element += '<div class="xxx"><img class="imgflex" src="' + item.src + '"><p class="imageHead">'
                    + item.name+'</p> <p class="imageText">' + item.plays+ '</p></div>';                  
                });
                document.getElementById("artist_container").innerHTML = element;
                console.log(data);
            }
        )
    }
)
```

I'm trying to convert it into the following jquery

```
$(_ =>{
    $.getJSON("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nabz123/9bef14fe98f95367887f827c3c5a0906/raw/01869dca62142c5ec0092316436cf3a7ecd7a8ec/topartists.json")
    ,function(data){
        let element ="";
        data.forEach((item) => {
            element += '<div class="xxx"><img class="imgflex" src="' + item.src + '"><p class="imageHead">'
            + item.name+'</p> <p class="imageText">' + item.plays+ '</p></div>';
        });
        document.getElementById("artist_container").innerHTML=element;
    }
});
```

I need help fixing my jquery, thanks

Comment: What's the problem with the code? Are there errors, or unexpected output, or what?

Comment: Could you please provide error logs or what this code do, any kinda expectation from it ?

Comment: Why would you convert to jQuery? Most people these days are going the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
data.forEach((item) => { code });
```

to

```
$.each(data, (i, item) => { code });
```

Change

```
document.getElementById("artist_container") = element;
```

to

```
$("#artist_container").html(element);
```